# grep + match quantity and numbers

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

with the following command I can verify/match if param have numbers or "."

```
  param=2.3.1
  echo $param |  grep [0-9][.]
```

but what I need to add in my syntax in order to verify also if I have at least two numbers (number  or more on the right side and number or more on the left side)

example of valid numbers

```
 12.2
 1.2
 4.3.0
 123.4.223
 12.33.22.4.2
 1.0.2.3.4
```

example of not valid numbers

```
 .39274
 1233.
 .7.
 .5666666.
 2...
```

Comment: [A regex for version number parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing)

Comment: this perl example I need  ksh /shellscript example

Comment: Fair enough, but you didn't say that anywhere, plus, which Linux doesn't have `perl`?

Answer (score 1):

This works in `bash`(I don't have `ksh`):

```
grep '^\([0-9]\+\.\)\+[0-9]\+$'
```

Comment: this example not work? echo 2.3.34.32_445454 | grep '^\([0-9]\+\.\)\+[0-9]\+$'

Comment: @Eytan: `echo 2.3.34.32.445454 | grep '^\([0-9]\+\.\)\+[0-9]\+$'` works. Why do you use `underscore(_)`?

Comment: because the numbers can be with any char as "_"

Comment: @Eytan change `[0-9]` to `[0-9_]`

Comment: this syntax not work on solaris